Path Analysis with a variable use d as grouping variable and predictor at the same time
I am conducting path analysis using structural equation modeling (SEM) and have a question regarding the use of a grouping variable in my model. One of my key longitudinal hypotheses is whether the association between household income and later income differs based on the level of household income.
To investigate this, I created a grouping variable (low/middle/high household income) and also used it as a predictor (continuous household income in each group) for later income. However, I’m unsure if this approach is justified. My concern is that grouping a continuous variable like household income reduces its variability in each group, which could impact the results.
Is using household income both as a grouping variable and predictor a viable option? If so, are there any references or studies that justify this method? Alternatively, are there other approaches I could consider for examining whether the relationship between household income and later income varies by income level?

This sounds like a non-linear regression problem to me.
You think that the slope of household income and later income varies across values of household income. I would use a quadratic regression here, rather than trichotomizing into three groups.  If you really want three straight lines, rather than 1 curved line, you can create a categorical variable and include this as a moderator - I suspect that would be easier than three groups.
In addition, you are choosing the points in advance - you might consider using some sort of spline regression to determine the best position of these points (combining that with SEM is probably going to be pretty tricky, but might be possible in Mplus using some sort of latent class analysis).

My guess is that you would run into severe collinearity issues with that approach since categorized income will be very highly (if not perfectly) correlated with continuous income. A multigroup path analysis may be a more viable option. In a multigroup analysis, you would formally (statistically) compare the autoregressive path coefficient for low, medium, and high income groups by using equality constraints. I have a Youtube video on how to run multigroup path analysis in Mplus (it would work similarly in lavaan, JASP, and other SEM programs):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRloHNbOzQs
